# how does open_spider metho fired on item pipeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.20 with python 2.7

According to [scrapy architecture](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html), the spider sends requests to the engine. Then, after the whole crawling process, the item goes through the item pipeline.

So, the item pipeline has nothing to do when the spider opens or closes. Also, item pipeline components can't know when the spider opens or closes. So, how the `open_spider` method exists in item pipeline components according to [this page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline)?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that you can implement open_spider() and close_spider() as callbacks if you want to. If you don't, your item pipeline will operate without awareness of the spider opens and closes. If you implement these routines, they will be called when the spider opens and closes. So if you want your item pipeline to take special action at when the spider opens and closes, you can make that happen by writing these routines in your pipeline.

Comment: these are not callbacks I guess. and my question is how the pipeline will know when the spider opens. according to the architecuture, the spider doesn't send any message to the item pipeline when starts working

Answer (score 0):

Having examined the architecture diagram and read the data flow description, I noted the following:

1. The data flow description does not explicitly state that spiders do not communicate with the item pipeline
2. Spiders and the item pipeline are linked via the scrapy engine, so presumably the engine is the process that informs the item pipeline that a spider has opened or closed, if `open_spider()` or `close_spider()` have been implemented

Comment: If this answer isn't acceptable, then it might be worth asking in the scrapy Google Group or contacting the developers directly for a more detailed description of the architecture and how spiders might communicate with item pipelines.